# Cannot import name 'artist' from 'matplotlib' (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I recently updated matplotlib and now I am consistently getting an error when I write from matplotlib import pyplot as plt.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'artist' from 'matplotlib' (C:\Users\nenze\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)`

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib which didn't solve anything. I even tried to downgrade to an older version but I am still getting the same error.

This is with matplotlib version 3.5.1. This is with Python version 3.9.7. This is through Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: Also I do not think I named any file named "matplotlib.py", which appears to be a common problem.

Comment: Do you have multiple matplotlib versions, and jupyter currently points to the wrong one? I had a similar problem, and the wrong version number gave it away, although I never found out why this had happened.

Comment: That's a good idea. How do I check to see if I have multiple versions?

Comment: Checking would be easiest through pip or conda. In fact you may have installed in both? But before pursuing that, try running `%pip install matplotlib` in a cell in your notebook & see if it fixes it. Then see if you can uninstall and force a reinstall from in the notebook, like advised [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/error-due-to-missing-dateutil-import-when-starting-jupyter-notebook/12773/2?u=fomightez) but putting `%` in front of those to use `%pip` magic. (Maybe try that in terminal if that fails.) If that doesn't fix it, try from a cell in your notebook `%conda install matplotlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up deleting Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py and it worked itself out.

I also deleted files that started with ~ (ex: ~matplotlib).